# Django formsets: make first required?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

These formsets are exhibiting exactly the *opposite* behavior that I want.

My view is set up like this:

```
def post(request): # TODO: handle vehicle formset
    VehicleFormSetFactory = formset_factory(VehicleForm, extra=1)
    if request.POST:
        vehicles_formset = VehicleFormSetFactory(request.POST)
    else:
        vehicles_formset = VehicleFormSetFactory()
```

And my template looks like this:

```
    <div id="vehicle_forms">
        {{ vehicles_formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in vehicles_formset.forms %}
            <h4>Vehicle {{forloop.counter}}</h4>
            <table>
                {% include "form.html" %}
            </table>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

That way it initially generates only 1 form, like I want. But I want that one form to be required!

When I dynamically add blank forms with JavaScript and `vehicles_formset.empty_form` all those extra forms are required, which I don't want.

From the docs:

> The formset is smart enough to ignore extra forms that were not changed.

This is the behavior the first form is exhibiting (not what I want) but not the behavior that the extra forms are exhibiting (what I do want).

Is there some attribute I can can change to at least make *one* form required?

Comment: @ mpen although I'm late for the party, I was wondering how to go about a slightly different issue that I'm facing my question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159559/need-to-have-a-required-and-optional-fields-in-django-formset)

Comment: @kedric You're asking the wrong guy. I haven't used Django since shortly after I posted this question.

Comment: ooh, Okay bro thanks for the response

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Found a better solution:

```
class RequiredFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RequiredFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False
```

Then create your formset like this:

```
MyFormSet = formset_factory(MyForm, formset=RequiredFormSet)
```

I *really* don't know why this wasn't an option to begin with... but, whatever. It only took a few hours of my life to figure out.

This will make all the forms required. You could make just the first one required by setting `self.forms[0].empty_permitted` to `False`.

Comment: This is the solution to one of the most annoying parts of Django, it's inexplicable why this isn't part of the documentation

Comment: For some reason, I get a keyError when trying to set a specific form to empty_permitted. For example "form[0].empty_permitted = False" gives an error.

Comment: @Zorpix Should be `self.forms[0]` I think, assuming you have at least one form.

Answer (score 29):

New in Django 1.7: you can specify this behaviour with your formset_factory

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/#validate-min

```
VehicleFormSetFactory = formset_factory(VehicleForm, min_num=1, validate_min=True, extra=1)
```

Comment: But, what if `extra=3` and the third form is filled and first two forms are left empty? This throws an error. How to implement this to be valid with atleast one form being valid one??

Comment: @whitehathackersree well, if Django does not behave that way then you will have to work around it somehow.  Comparing the source code (https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7.11/django/forms/formsets.py#L314 vs https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.15/django/forms/formsets.py#L332) it looks like this may have been fixed in Django 1.11

Comment: This still does not set the `required` attribute on the input fields, as in, it is still possible to submit the form (it will just return with an error since you didn't fill out the form correctly).

Answer (score 10):

Well... this makes the first form required.

```
class RequiredFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        if any(self.errors):
            return
        if not self.forms[0].has_changed():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Please add at least one vehicle.')
```

Only "problem" is that if there are 0 forms, then the `clean` method doesn't seem to get called at all, so I don't know how to check if there are 0. Really...this should never happen though (except that my JS has a bug in it, allowing you to remove *all* the forms).

Comment: If you use this form to edit an existing set of objects, you will always be forced to update the first one. This is only suitable for creation, not updating.

Comment: @Daniel Palm , do you have a solution ? I also have  same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Oh I think I see. Try this:

```
from django.forms.formsets import BaseFormSet, formset_factory
class OneExtraRequiredFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def initial_form_count(self):
        return max(super(OneExtraRequiredFormSet,self).initial_form_count() - 1,0)

VehicleFormSetFactory = formset_factory(VehicleForm, formset=OneExtraRequiredFormSet, extra=1)
```

== Original answer below ==

When you say "at least make one form required", I assume you mean "make only one extra form required, regardless of how many have been added via javascript".

You will need to have hidden input on your page which contains the number of forms that have been added via javascript, and then use that number, minus 1, as the value to pass in as the `extra` attribute to your formsets constructor.

Comment: Not quite... ignoring the JavaScript for now, one and only one form is displayed (extra=1, no initial data). That *one* form is not required -- I want it to be. Any forms added via JS should *not* be required, ever.

Comment: That has some bizarre behavior. When I leave the form blank and submit it, it adds another one and puts errors on the new form, and still doesn't validate the first one.

Comment: Hmm ok try it without overriding the total_form_count method.

Comment: (just fixed a typo, it should of course be max instead of min in the initial_form_count method)

Comment: Nope. Don't think you can do it by playing with the counts.