# Django formset doesn't validate

Tags: django, forms, formset

I am trying to save a formset but it seems to be bypassing is_valid() even though there are required fields.

To test this I have a simple form:

```
class AlbumForm(forms.Form):
  name = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

The view:

```
@login_required
def add_album(request, artist):
  artist = Artist.objects.get(slug__iexact=artist)
  AlbumFormSet = formset_factory(AlbumForm)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = AlbumFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if formset.is_valid():
      return HttpResponse('worked')
  else:
    formset = AlbumFormSet()
  return render_to_response('submissions/addalbum.html', {
   'artist': artist,
   'formset': formset,
  }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And the template:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset.forms %}
  <ul class="addalbumlist">
    {% for field in form %}
     <li>
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
        {{ field.errors }}
     </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
   <div class="inpwrap">
    <input type="button" value="add another">
    <input type="submit" value="add">
   </div>
</form>
```

---

What ends up happening is I hit "add" without entering a name then HttpResponse('worked') get's called seemingly assuming it's a valid form.

I might be missing something here, but I can't see what's wrong. What I want to happen is, just like any other form if the field is required to spit out an error if its not filled in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Heh, I was having this exact same problem. The problem is that you're using a formset!! Formsets allow *all* fields in a form to be blank. If, however, you have 2 fields, and fill out only one, *then* it will recognize your required stuffs. It does this because formsets are made for "bulk adding" and sometimes you don't want to fill out all the extra forms on a page. Really annoying; you can see [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406537/django-formsets-make-first-required/2422221#2422221) here.

Answer (score 5):

For each of the fields that are required, add an extra entry in the attrs parameter

```
    resident_status = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'required': 'required'}), choices=President.RESIDENT_STATUS,
        required=True)
```

As you can see, I maintain the required=True for django's form validation but specify 'required':'required' for the template to insist for the field be required.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 lines.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
  def initial_form_count(self): return 10 # the number of forms
  AlbumFormSet.initial_form_count = initial_form_count
  formset = AlbumFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -4):

use:

> if not any(formset.errors): ...

instead of:

> if formset.is_valid(): ...

Comment: `formset.errors` will not be filled until `formset.is_valid()` is called, so this solution totally won't work.