# Validation of modelformsets from modelforms

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

One view I have is using a modelform with custom field cleaning. One type of cleaning is checking if the user is trying to submit a change to a field that is already set to the value, and it works exactly how I want it to work by throwing a ValidationError. The problem of course is that I can only submit one form at a time, so I'd like to use a modelformset to submit multiple forms.

I know it is possible to override the modelformset's clean method, but **I'm asking if it's possible to use the modelform's field cleaning methods on the modelformset?**. Currently when I submit the modelformset with empty fields the is_valid() passes which seems strange to me...

I also would like to know "typically" where the custom modelformset validation code would go? I was thinking with the forms.py.

*Edit -- with answer. My httpResponseRedirect was allowing the form to be submitted without validation.

```
def mass_check_in(request):
    # queryset
    qs = Part.objects.none()
    errlst=[]
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    # Creating a model_formset out of PartForm
    PartFormSetFactory = modelformset_factory(model=Part,
                                              form=PartForm,
                                              formset=BasePartFormSet, 
                                              extra=2)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        PartFormSet = PartFormSetFactory(request.POST)
        if PartFormSet.is_valid():
            PartFormSet.save()
            return http.HttpResponseRedirect('/current_count/')

    else:        
        PartFormSet = PartFormSetFactory(queryset=qs, initial=[
                                                               {'serial_number':'placeholder',
                                                                },
                                                               {'serial_number':'placeholder'
                                                                }])

    return render(request,'mass_check_in.html',{
                                           'title':'Add Item',
                                           'formset': PartFormSet,
                                           'formset_errors': PartFormSet.non_form_errors(),
                                           })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't enter any data at all in one of the modelforms in your model formset, it will skip validation for that form; [from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#formset-validation):

> The formset is smart enough to ignore extra forms that were not changed.

You can actually disable this functionality though by forcing `empty_permitted=False` on the forms; see the accepted answer to this question for more: [Django formsets: make first required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406537/django-formsets-make-first-required)

Formsets do [have their own `clean` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation), but it's used to validate information between two or more forms in the formset, not for validating the individual forms themselves (which should be taken care of in the forms `clean` method - as you are doing now.

> A formset has a clean method similar to the one on a Form class. This is where you define your own validation that works at the formset level:

Here's another similar question:

[Django formset doesn't validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452131/django-formset-doesnt-validate)

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation! But for some reason my  modelformset isn't validating at the form level and/or at the formset level. my code is here ---> http://dpaste.com/787964/. Thank you Timmy.