# django required=True not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have this very simple form and I want that the only field must not be empty.
So in the doc, required=True is the answer :

```
class AjouterGroupe(forms.Form):
    nom = forms.CharField(required=True, label="", max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Nom', 'class':'form-control input-perso'}))
```

This is some of my view :

```
Formset = formset_factory(data.form(table, 1), extra=nbajout)
        if request.method == 'POST' and first:

            formset = Formset(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if formset.is_valid():
                nbajout = 0  
                envoi = True

                for form in formset:
                    print(form.is_valid())
                    print(form)
                    form.save()

            form = nbAjout()

        else:
            formset = Formset()
```

In a particular case, data.form(table, 1)=AjouterGroupe.

But the main issue is that form.is_valid() is True when I validate with an empty field :/

```
Variable                    Value

csrfmiddlewaretoken     'uw1fFj9toTU3o3Il3lFW0yvt4OS31XUn'

form-INITIAL_FORMS    '0'

form-MAX_NUM_FORMS    '1000'

form-TOTAL_FORMS     '1'

form-MIN_NUM_FORMS    '0'

form-0-nom            ''
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because `Formsets` do allow blank values. If nothing is entered, it will be considered as a form that doesn't need to be added.

Try with your form on its own (not part of a formset): there, your `required=True` will work fine. Also, if you'd try with a model with two fields (both set to `required=True`) you'll see that an error is thrown if only one field is filled.

You should be able to play around with `formset_factory` parameters like `min_num=<number>, validate_min=True, extra=1` etc. to force the verification.

See also [Django formset doesn't validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452131/django-formset-doesnt-validate).