# Django formset validation strange behavior

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I got some strange behavior with formset validation for model form formset.
I'am using Django 1.5, python 2.7
Here is code what i used.

Model class:

```
class WorkDone(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    type_of_work = models.ForeignKey("pricelist.TypeOfWork")
```

Form class:

```
class WorkDoneForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = WorkDone
        exclude = ("task",)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WorkDoneForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["type_of_work"].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Formset class generation:

```
WorkDoneFormSet = formset_factory(WorkDoneForm, can_delete=True)
```

Formset creation in get_context_data function of view:

```
context["work_done_formset"] = context.get("work_done_formset", WorkDoneFormSet(prefix='work_done'))
```

So, i submit form with one WorkDone form in formset without any entered data(for typeOfWork of course) and here POST data from POST request:

```
QueryDict: {u'_save': [u''],  
    u'work_done-0-type_of_work': [u''],  
    u'work_done-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'0'], 
    u'work_done-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'1'], 
    u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'nFkTCyx3413yrFE9XpNQDGdNlzPAHwyI'], 
    u'work_done-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000']}
```

And output from this code bellow in view:

```
work_done_formset = WorkDoneFormSet(request.POST, prefix="work_done")
print work_done_formset.is_valid(), work_done_formset.cleaned_data
for form in work_done_formset:
    print form.is_valid(), form.cleaned_data

>> True [{}]
>> True {}
```

Why validation is true and why there is no error for missing TypeOfWork fields in form? Thank you.

Comment: This is because nothing has changed in the formset. The validation per form triggers only when something has changed in the individual form of the formset

Comment: So, i need to set the default value for form field for validation trigger? Or, maybe, initial form count > 0?

Comment: well. even that would not work - because django formsets have a property called `formset.has_changed()` which would not change. If you have only 1 form, why not just go with a single form ?

Comment: No, there can be many forms, because they can be added via js on user-side.

Comment: Oh.. One thing you can do is, override the `def clean` method of the and ensure atleast one form is filled.

Comment: So, there is no way without overriding BaseFormset class? Or, i can use default value in such fields, so field will not be null by default, or user will change it value so validation will trigger?

Comment: Well. Thats the only way I can think of. Lets wait and see if someone else has a better idea. I would be keen to know too :)

Comment: One more alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4951032/1628832

Comment: Setting `empty_permitted` on one or all of my forms after instantiating the formset, as demonstrated in that answer, is how I've solved this in the past.