# BaseModelFormSet __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, django

I am getting the above error when I have tried to convert my inline_formset to have at least the first row required. [(please see here for the StackOverflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406537/django-formsets-make-first-required)

My existing code is below:

```
#views.py
def application(request, job_id):
    job = get_object_or_404(Job, pk=job_id)
    #return 404 if job isn't yet published
    if (job.pub_date>timezone.now() or job.close_date<timezone.now()):
        return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Job not found</h1>')

    #create all the inlineformsets (can_delete) set to false as will always be empty upon population
    EducationInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Applicant, Education, extra=1, can_delete=False)
    QualificationInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Applicant, Qualification, extra=1, can_delete=False)
    EmploymentInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Applicant, Employment, extra=1, can_delete=False)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        applicant = Applicant(job=job)
        form = ApplicantForm(request.POST, instance=applicant)
        bottom_form = ApplicantFormBottom(request.POST, instance=applicant)
        education_formset = EducationInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=applicant)
        qualification_formset = QualificationInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=applicant)
        employment_formset = EmploymentInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=applicant)

        #check all of the forms and formsets are valid
        if form.is_valid() and bottom_form.is_valid() and education_formset.is_valid() and qualification_formset.is_valid() and employment_formset.is_valid():
            # save the model to database, directly from the form:
            form.save()
            bottom_form.save()
            education_formset.save()
            qualification_formset.save()
            employment_formset.save()
            return render(request, 'jobs/success.html')


    else:
        applicant = Applicant(job=job)
        form = ApplicantForm(instance=applicant)
        bottom_form = ApplicantFormBottom(instance=applicant)
        education_formset = EducationInlineFormSet(instance=applicant)
        qualification_formset = QualificationInlineFormSet(instance=applicant)
        employment_formset = EmploymentInlineFormSet(instance=applicant)


    c = { 
    'job' : job,
    'form' : form ,
    'bottom_form' : bottom_form,
    'education_formset' : education_formset,
    'qualification_formset' : qualification_formset,
    'employment_formset' : employment_formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'jobs/application.html', c)
```

In order to customise the formset I defined the following:

```
class BaseFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False
```

and pass use it as follows:

```
EducationInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Applicant, Education, extra=1, can_delete=False, formset=BaseFormSet)
```

This returns the above error and having read around a lot I'm still none the wiser how I can keep passing an instance to the formset.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Chris.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue - the problem was the customised formset.

Try subclassing from `BaseInlineFormSet` (not `BaseModelFormSet`).

Here is the relevant section of [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-methods-on-an-inlineformset).