# Append to Django Form Validation Error?

Tags: python, html, django, validation, django-forms

I'm using custom validation error in Django 1.6 and it's working great; however, I can only display one error at a time.  How do I go about displaying all errors if the condition in the "if" statements failed?

**forms.py**

```
class BaseNameFormSet (BaseFormSet):
...
...
...
if (firstname in firstnames) or (lastname in lastnames):
    raise forms.ValidationError ('First or last name must be unique')
if (firstname == '') or (lastname == ''):
    raise forms.ValidationError ('Both first and last name must be filled out')
```

**addname.html**

```
...
...
...
    {% if formset.non_form_errors %}
        <b>Please correct the error below:</b>
        <ul>
            {% for error in formset.non_form_errors %}
            <li><p style="color: red;"> {{ error }} </p></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to upgrade to Django 1.7, you can [raise multiple errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/validation/#raising-multiple-errors) by passing a list  to the `ValidationError` constructor.

```
errors = []
if (firstname in firstnames) or (lastname in lastnames):
    errors.append('First or last name must be unique')
if (firstname == '') or (lastname == ''):
    errors.append('Both first and last name must be filled out')
if errors:
    raise ValidationError(errors)
```

Note that you shouldn't usually have to do checks like `if firstname == ''`, just make `firstname` a required field. You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406537/django-formsets-make-first-required/2422221) about making a forms in a formset required to be useful.

Comment: Upgrading to Django 1.7 won't be an easy option at this point.  I've seen documentation that uses an error list but thought there was a better way.  Also, the "required" field in Django doesn't work quite right when you have an empty string.  It will pass as a valid form; hence, I had to do it this way.  I appreciate your suggestion nevertheless.

Comment: The above method has worked for me without upgrading.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: For bound forms, `CharFields` *will* give errors for empty strings. In your case, because you're using a formset, you need the checks for completely empty, unbound forms. I've added a link to a question that you might find useful. Note that support for Django 1.6 will end once Django 1.8 is released ([perhaps in April](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Version1.8Roadmap)), so you should think about upgrading soon.

Comment: Thanks again Alasdair.  I've ran into that link before but felt that it didn't fit in my case.  Now it does so I'll give it another look.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable that is filled with the errors, then display it once at the end.

```
class BaseNameFormSet (BaseFormSet):
    ...
    ...
    ...

    if (firstname in firstnames) or (lastname in lastnames):
         error_msg='First or last name must be unique'
    if (firstname == '') or (lastname == ''):
        error_msg+='<br>Both first and last name must be filled out'
    if error_msg:
        raise forms.ValidationError(error_msg)
```

Comment: Brilliant idea.  I'll see which of the 2 works best for my case.  Thank you!!